# Execute update Method inside datatable

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jpa

I'm facing problem with Hibernate ,

So I have a datatable that contain a list of objects , this is my xhtml article.xhtml :

```
<b:dataTable value="#{gestionCommandeController.commandes2}"
        var="commande">

        <b:dataTableColumn value="#{commande.idComm}"
            label="Identifiant Commande" />

        <h:column label="Details Commande">
            <h:form>

                <b:commandButton value="modal" ajax="true" update="amodal"
                    look="info" oncomplete=" $('#amodal').modal('show')"
                    actionListener="#{gestionCommandeController.consulterCommande(commande.idComm)}"></b:commandButton>
            </h:form>
        </h:column>

        <h:column label="Confirmer Commande">

            <h:form
                rendered="#{gestionCommandeController.etatCommande(commande.idComm)}"
                style="text-align=center">
                <b:commandButton value="Confirmer"
                    actionListener="#{gestionCommandeController.passerCommande(commande.idComm)}"
                    look="success"></b:commandButton>
            </h:form>

            <h:form
                rendered="#{!gestionCommandeController.etatCommande(commande.idComm)}">
                <b:commandButton value="Stock epuisé"
                    actionListener="#{gestionCommandeController.passerCommande(commande.idComm)}"
                    look="danger" disabled="true"></b:commandButton>
            </h:form>
        </h:column>

    </b:dataTable>
```

In the Managed Bean GestionCommandeController :

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{loginController.user}")
private Object user;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EJB
GestionCommandeLocal commandeLocal;

List<Boolean> testStrock;

public Boolean testPassCommande = true;


public List<CommandeArticle> consulterCommande(int id) {

    commande = commandeLocal.getCommandeById(id);
    commandeArticles = commandeArticleLocal
            .findCommandeArticleByCommande(commande);

    return commandeArticles;
}

public void passerCommande(int id) {

    Commande commande = new Commande();
    commande = commandeLocal.getCommandeById(id);

    commandeLocal.updateCommande(commande);

        commandes2 = commandeLocal.getAllCommandes();

}
```

the updateCommande method exist in the Session Bean :

```
@Override
public Boolean updateCommande(Commande commande) {
    try {
        em.merge(commande);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
```

the method passerCommande(int id) didn't work , when I execute this method outside the datatable it works fine , but in the datatable it cause an incomprehensible  error:

```
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3697) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:439) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:251) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:954) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:903) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:610) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:658) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:756) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:635) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:856) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2058) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3697) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:439) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:251) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:954) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:903) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:610) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:658) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:756) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:635) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:856) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2058) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3697) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:439) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:251) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:954) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:903) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:610) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:658) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:756) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:635) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:856) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2058) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3697) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:439) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:251) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:954) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:903) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:610) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:658) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:756) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:635) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:856) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2058) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3697) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:439) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:251) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:954) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:903) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:610) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:658) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:756) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:635) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:856) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2058) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3697) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:439) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:251) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:954) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:903) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:610) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:658) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:756) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:635) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:856) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2058) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3697) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:439) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:251) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:954) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:903) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:610) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:658) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:756) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:635) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:856) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2058) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3697) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:439) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
```

Is there any solutions ??

Comment: Could you, please, paste full exception stacktrace with error message?

Comment: @user629735: given the recursion in the stack trace, it's a stack overflow error (i.e. the code ran in an infinite loop).